# Converting MP3 data to OGG using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am working in a project where I need to take some mp3 samples and mix them up in an ogg file as output.

Kind of like what this website does: http://naturesoundsfor.me/

While researching I stumbled upon this library, which seems to do what I want: 
http://labs.byhook.com/2011/02/22/ogg-vorbis-encoder-decoder-for-flash/

But, when I encode a 2 minutes mp3 file, it becomes just a 2 seconds ogg file. Here is my code:

```
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
_sound.extract(bytes, _sound.length); // the sound is fully loaded from mp3 file

_oggManager.addEventListener(OggManagerEvent.ENCODE_COMPLETE, onEncodeComplete);

private function onEncodeComplete(e:OggManagerEvent):void 
{
    _oggManager.removeEventListener(OggManagerEvent.ENCODE_COMPLETE, onEncodeComplete);

    var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
    fileRef.save(_oggManager.encodedBytes, "newFile.ogg");
}
```

But the output ends up with just a part of the audio. I am not really familiar with sound encoding and decoding, so there must be something I am missing or not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer at this great article about how the extract method works and how audio data is stored in flash: http://www.marinbezhanov.com/web-development/14/actionscript-3-sound-extract-demystified-or-how-to-draw-a-waveform-in-flash/

The fix for the code is in the extract part. Has to be like this:

```
_sound.extract(bytes, (_sound.length / 1000) * 44100);
```

The length property of the Sound class returns the length in milliseconds, so we convert it to seconds and then multiply by the sample rate, which is always 44.1khz in flash.